# Не видит INPUT TYPE FILE

Tags: php, html, форма

Дорогие друзья есть самая простая форма

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-validate-jquery" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="display-block">Загрузить картинку:</label>
<input type="file" required name="image"  class="file-styled" accept="image/*">     
</div>
<button type="submit" name = "add_art" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить <i 
class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button></form>
```

Обрабатываю эту форму я так

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$random_date = date('Y-m-d') ;                              
$random = (rand(0,9999));
$mic = uniqid();
$image= file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_name= ($random_date.$mic.$random.$_FILES['image']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../assets/images/" . $image_name);         
$location="assets/images/" . $image_name;
```

Но даже когда я загружаю картинку то PHP выдает ошибку

> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\dirname\index.php on line 149
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\dirname\index.php on line 153
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\dirname\index.php on line 153
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\dirname\index.php on line 154
>
> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\dirname\index.php on line 155

Хотя через форму файл выбирается пользователем ..в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\dirname\index.php on line 153

file_get_contets зачем вам. у вас уже файл на хосте в /tmp/

Comment: вопрос в том что даже если и  файл выбирается то скрипт говорит что там пусто

Comment: работайте  с $_FILES['image'], копируйте куда нужно через copy()

Comment: sterx, благодарю Вас за ответы. Но Вы по моему немного не туда двигаетесь. Как я могу обработать через $_FILES['image'] когда он говорит что там пусто )

Comment: var_dump(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

если покажет false значит настройки PHP надо глянуть

Comment: я и print_r пробовал там пусто. Самое интересное в другом скрипте именно такой расклад работает